# Support for Objection `$formatJson` in ApolloServer

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server, objection.js

I'm a big fan of both [Objection.js](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/) and [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) and I'm trying to get them to work together for a new API at my business. Unfortunately, I'm having some difficulties.

One of the best things about Objection is the [model data lifecyle](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/overview.html#model-data-lifecycle) which allows you to specify inside a model class how to translate its properties between various formats. You can store it the database in one way, work with it in your code in another way, and serialize it before sending it to a client in yet another way.

[$formatJson](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/instance-methods.html#formatjson), for example, can be used to change Date properties that are JS Date objects when you're working with the model, but are turned into ISO strings when sent in a response:

```
$formatJson(json: Pojo): Pojo {
    json = super.$formatJson(json);
    if (json.lastActive) json.lastActive = json.lastActive.toISOString();
    return json;
}
```

This method is invoked in the instance's `#toJSON` method, which would normally be invoked when stringifying as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Description).

ApolloServer (specifically [apollo-server-koa](https://www.npmjs.com/package/apollo-server-koa) which I am using) does not stringify these model instances directly, however. It seems to (reasonably) copy subsets of properties to new objects, separating the data from its instance methods. Thus, `#$formatJson` will never be called, and my Dates come back as timestamps since that's how JS Dates stringify by default.

It seems need to somehow inject some `#toJSON` calls in between the resolver functions and the copying of properties from their return values. I looked into `formatResponse`[here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/) but it looks like that receives the data after it has already been separated from the Model classes.

Would anybody who is familiar with ApolloServer be able to point me in the right direction? Is there some sort of plugin API I need to look into?

I found [objection-graphql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objection-graphql) which is super cool, but it looks like it handles this by handling the entire query in a top-level resolver and recursively calling `#toJSON` on everything before the resolver even returns. The default resolvers pick up everything else from the eager-loaded structure. Super cool, but it doesn't look like it will be flexible enough for my needs. Really I just want to solve this specific problem and not magic away my entire api. :\

---

EDIT:

I've done some more research on this and I'd like to state the problem a bit more clearly, now that I've got a better grasp on how GraphQL is actually implemented.

GraphQL works by invoking your resolvers and assembling the response property-by-property. Your top-level resolvers are invoked first, and after they return, resolvers for each property the next level down are invoked, and so on until only leaves remain. The return values of each leaf end up assigned into an object structure that is stringified to JSON. This means that any instance methods on the objects that these properties originally came from are completely lost by this point. So if you're looking to do some kind of "final" transformation on the whole result using those instance methods (in this case, Objection's `$formatJSON`), you're going to have some difficulties.

**The Difficulties**

It is possible, using [graphql-middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-middleware), to intercept the result of any resolver and recursively invoke your transformation on its contents, using something like this:

```
import { isArray, isObjectLike, map, mapValues } from 'lodash';
import { resolvers, typeDefs } from './api';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-koa';
import Koa from 'koa';
import { Model } from 'objection';
import { applyMiddleware } from 'graphql-middleware';

function toResponse(value: any): any {
    // If this isn't an object or an array, just return it.
    if (!isObjectLike(value)) return value;

    // If this is an instance of Model, convert it using #$toJson
    if (value instanceof Model) return value.$toJson();

    // Create a recursive mapping function.
    const mapFn = (item: any) => toResponse(item);

    /*
     * If this an array, convert each one of its items with the mapping
     * function.
     */
    if (isArray(value)) return map(value, mapFn);

    /*
     * Otherwise, this must be an object. Convert its values with the mapping
     * function.
     */
    return mapValues(value, mapFn);
}

const schema = applyMiddleware(
    makeExecutableSchema({ typeDefs, resolvers }),
    async(
        resolve,
        root,
        args,
        info,
    ) => toResponse(await resolve(root, args, ctx, info)),
);

const app = new Koa();
const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });
server.applyMiddleware({ app });

app.listen(3000);
```

The issue here is that the transformation will happen *before* your lower-level resolvers are called to traverse deeper into the graph. Thus, the first argument of those resolvers will receive these transformed Model instances, and *these* will no longer have any of the helpful instance methods of the original Model class (like `$relatedQuery`) which you might want to implement the resolver.

For example, I might have a simple schema like this:

```
type Query {
    person(id: Int!): Person
}

type Person {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    children: [Person!]
}
```

And implement my resolvers like this:

```
{
    Query: {
        person: (
            root: undefined,
            args: { id: number },
        ) => Person.query().findById(args.id),
    },
    Person: {
        children: (person: Person) => person.$relatedQuery('children'),
    },
}
```

With the middleware setup shown above, this resolver for Person.children would not work, since its the `person` argument would not be receiving an instance of `Model`, and as such it would not have the `$relatedQuery` instance method.

**Why:**

Why would someone want this? Aside from simply wanting to use one of Objection's best features (which, as Herku correctly points out, could probably be handled better using something more specific to GQL in this case), there's also the possibility of integration with other libraries that make similar assumptions about your API framework that Objection does.

I left this bit out originally for simplicty's sake, but I also have a (currently proprietary) permissions library that's capable of filtering the results of queries to remove properties that the user is not allowed to see based on various factors. The way I'm currently planning on integrating this also involves a "post resolver" transformation of my models that needs the original Model instances. I may or may not go down that path, and I don't want to share too much about how this library works at the moment, but hopefully that makes the case somewhat more clear.

I have found a sort of work-around approach that seems to work and will be posting an answer soon, unless someone else comes up with something better.

Answer (score 1):

So in GraphQL objects are not directly transformed to JSON. Instead there are only a few places where a value is turned into a JSON value. That is inside of the Leaf Types.

Leaf Types are types without subselections in GraphQL. Concretely, these are *Scalar* and *Enum*. Let's see how we can work with values internally but different values externally:

For enum types we can define different values internally than externally. You can assign anything you want to the value property:

```js
import { GraphQLEnumType } from 'graphql';

const MyEnum = new GraphQLEnumType({
  name: 'MyEnum',
  values: {
    VALUE_A: {
      value: 'value-a',
    },
    VALUE_B: {
      value: 'value-b',
    }
  }
});
```

If you use Apollo and `graphql-tools` you have to do it [slightly differently](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/#internal-values). Now for the more interesting Scalar case. In your example dates could be serialized by a Date Scalar.

```js
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';
import { Kind } from 'graphql/language';

const Date = new GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'Date',
  description: 'Date custom scalar type',
  parseValue(value) {
    return new Date(value); // value from JSON (from variable)
  },
  serialize(value) {
    return value.toISOString(); // serialization happens here
  },
  parseLiteral(ast) {
    if (ast.kind === Kind.STRING) {
      return new Date(ast.value); // value inlined in query
    }
    return null;
  },
});
```

Now we serialize as ISO string and internally use JavaScript dates! Again Apollo is [a bit different](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/scalars/#custom-graphqlscalartype-instance).

If you don't want to write your own Scalar types for that matter check out [Uri's GraphQL Scalars](https://github.com/Urigo/graphql-scalars). Or [GraphQL ISO Date](https://github.com/excitement-engineer/graphql-iso-date) which does pretty much the thing in my example.

Comment: So obviously a custom scalar type could be helpful for adding dates to the schema, but my question is specifically about integrating Objection with Apollo and date formatting specifically is just an example of a transformation that can be done with Objection's `$formatJson`.

Comment: Basically, I just want to be able to return Model instances to my resolvers and have Apollo to invoke `$toJson` on them before serializing the full response data.

Comment: I think Apollo/GraphQL solves what `$formatJson` does in a different way. I have outlined the way how it is done in GraphQL here. I don't think that you need `$formatJson` because this is what GraphQL is all about. I would be interested in how what you are proposing is better than what Apollo does. So if you find a solution please share it! :)

Comment: It isn't necessarily better, it's just more in line with how Objection is designed, which aims not to couple your serialization logic to what kind of API you're serving your entities over. If, for example, I wanted to serve the same entities over a non-GQL endpoint, I'd have to duplicate the serialization logic between my custom scalar types (used by GraphQL) and whatever I'd use to perform serialization for these other APIs.

Comment: It may well be that what I'm asking for is not architecturally possible with the way most GQL implementations work, which is starting to seem like the case. I'd like to rule that out, though, just for sake of being thorough.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround I've found involves using the same `graphql-middleware` approach detailed in my edit, plus storing references to the original Model instance on the transformed objects. These references are keyed to a [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) to guarantee no collision is possible with any property names in the result.

The following will be used as a base class for all of my database models:

```
import { Model as ObjectionModel, Pojo } from 'objection';

export const entitySymbol = Symbol('Model instance');

export class Model extends ObjectionModel {
    $toJson(): Pojo {
        const result = super.$toJson();
        // Retain a reference to the original entity.
        result[entitySymbol] = this;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Meanwhile, this module provides a function which can be used to wrap my resolvers and extract the reference where necessary:

```
import { Model, entitySymbol } from './model';
import { IFieldResolver } from 'apollo-server-koa';
import { GraphQLResolveInfo } from 'graphql';

export interface ResponseEntity<T> {
    [entitySymbol]: T;
}

export type EntityResolver<
    TEntity extends Model,
    TContext = any,
    TArgs = Record<string, any>,
> = (
    entity: TEntity,
    args: TArgs,
    context: TContext,
    info: GraphQLResolveInfo,
) => any;

export function entityResolver<
    TEntity extends Model,
    TContext = any,
    TArgs = Record<string, any>,
>(
    resolver: EntityResolver<TEntity, TContext, TArgs>,
): IFieldResolver<ResponseEntity<TEntity>, TContext, TArgs> {
    return (
        obj: ResponseEntity<TEntity>,
        args: TArgs,
        context: TContext,
        info: GraphQLResolveInfo,
    ) => resolver(obj[entitySymbol], args, context, info);
```

Now I can implement my resolvers like this:

```
{
    Query: {
        person: (
            root: undefined,
            args: { id: number },
        ) => Person.query().findById(args.id),
    },
    Person: {
        children: entityResolver(
            (person: Person) => person.$relatedQuery('children'),
        ),
    },
}
```

The use of the symbol feels a little bit hacky but it seems robust enough, and ultimately I can't see how there could be a better way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Objection has the static method [`fromJson`](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/model/static-methods.html#static-fromjson) to create a model instance that you can use like this:

```
{
    Query: {
        ...
    },
    Person: {
        children: (person: Person) => Person.fromJson(person).$relatedQuery('children'),
    },
}
```

Comment: So this could work in place of the symbol, but it relies on the assumption that `$formatJson` will not destroy any properties necessary for that `$relatedQuery` to work. If, for example, it was used (for whatever reason) to filter out a Person's `id` field which corresponds to the `mother_id` and `father_id` fields of other Person records, the `$relatedQuery` could fail. In this particular example that sounds contrived, but it is something that could come up in practice.